# Как в notepad++ вставить текст рядом столбцом

Tags: notepad++

Есть текстовое поле, примерным содержанием

```
123
1234
12345
123
```

как я могу вставить из буфера обмена, рядом столбцом другой текст что бы можно было визуально сравнивать строки

что в итоге должно получиться

```
123     543
1234    5432
12345   54321
123     5432
```

Comment: А sublime text не подойдёт? не думаю что такое можно легко сделать в notepad++
Вот в нём это делается в пару кликов

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей, будет полезно

Comment: Лучше возьми Excel или аналог. Там можно не только сравнивать, но и при необходимости добавлять ячеек, если строка-другая пропущена..

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте плагин Compare, создайте два файла, в плагине выберите один файл и выберите файл в сравнение. Вы не только сможете визуально сравнивать файлы, но будут подсвечены различия.